# Conditions on navigation properties using LINQ Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, contains

I am trying to pull all the `Institutions` and non-trashed `InstitutionUsers` based on the groups the users belong to. An `Institution` has `InstitutionUsers` and `InstitutionUsers` have `InvestigatorGroups` (an institution has groups as well). I know my where has issues, any help is much appreciated

```
public class InstitutionRepository : IInstitutionRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Institution> GetInstitutionGroupUsers(IEnumerable<int> groupIds)
    {
        using (var context = new GameDbContext())
        {

            return context.Institutions
                .Include(i => i.InstitutionUsers)
                .Where(i => i.InstitutionUsers
                    .Select(g => g.IsTrashed)
                        .Contains(false) && groupIds.Contains(i.InstitutionUsers.Select(g => g.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Select(x => x.InvestigatorGroupId)))).ToArray().ToList();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get a list of `Institution` having at least one `InstitutionUser` with `IsTrashed=false` and being associated with at least one `InvestigationGroup` with `Id` contained in the passed `groupIds` filter.

If that's true, then the following query should produce the desired result

```
return context.Institutions
    .Include(i => i.InstitutionUsers)
    .Where(i => i.InstitutionUsers.Any(u => !u.IsTrashed && 
        u => u.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Any(gu => groupIds.Contains(gu.InvestigatorGroupId))))
    .ToList();
```